# Intersection of filter parameters for Tweetstream client

Tags: ruby, filter, rubygems, tweetstream

I am using the [tweetstream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream) ruby gem to retrieve statuses from Twitter.

I am combining filter parameters in this way:

```
TweetStream::Client.new.filter({:track => ['bbc'], :locations=> '-2.0,50,1,52' } ) do |tweet|
  p tweet.inspect
end
```

This creates a stream that is the union of the two parameters (all tweets within the bounding box, AND all tweets containing the term 'bbc').

Does anyone how to create a stream that is the intersection of multiple filter parameters. In this case, each tweet should contain the term 'bbc' and also be within the bounding box?

Comment: I don't know the API, but perhaps you can chain the filters in some way like `filter({:track => ['bbc']) ... filter(:locations=> '-2.0,50,1,52' })`. You might need some code for `...`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response sawa. I've tried a couple of chaining techniques, including `TweetStream::Client.new.filter({:track => ['bbc']}).filter({:locations=> '-9.05,48.77,2.19,58.88' } )`but this resulted in no tweets being streamed.